# Sending input to a cmd window using vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, psexec

I am trying to automate my process. I need to ask the user for the computer name ex: SH010123 store that as a variable. start cmd prompt. type `psexec\\"computername" cmd` then I need to type `net use t: \\network\path password /user:domain\username` and finally type `\\network\path\"my file.bat"`

I cant figure out how to use vbscript to send those inputs to a cmd window.

Comment: There are methods for doing just about everything without resorting to opening a command prompt. That should be your last resort.

Comment: psexec is executed in a command prompt window. Thats why I am trying to do it this way. I dont know of another way of doing it

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you really trying to do?

Comment: Use psexec to run a .bat file on a remote computer. this .bat file is USMT (captures user data and sends it to a network drive). I also want this to run in the background without the end user knowing. But the .bat file is on a network drive that needs a admin account privilege to access.

Comment: So use WSShell's .Exec() or .Run() method to execute psexec. You can pass the batch file to run and admin credentials when you run psexec. There is no need to open the cmd prompt. you could also run it on the remote machine by starting a new process via WMI. Also does not require opening a prompt.

Comment: & joins commands together. so psexec\\ "computername" cmd&\\net use t: \\network&\\computer\share\myfile.bat. None of your commands will work because of your quotes and spaces being wrong. This runs a cmd window hidden CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False. This starts programs remotely (plus you can also use schtasks) wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call create cmd \\computer\share\myfile.bat

Comment: So I have this line. psexec \\%asset% -u domian\user -p password cmd&\\network\path\path\"file .bat". everything but the & part is working. Do I have it wrong?

Comment: \\network\path\path\"file .bat" WRONG "\\network\path\path\file .bat" RIGHT but having a trailing space, while legal, the graphical shell, ie explorer, will remove it.

Comment: You do understand your commands are unrelated to each other. One starts a command pronmpt and does nothing else. One runs a bat file (but has nothing to do with your command prompt).

Comment: Yes psexec opens a command prompt window. when you psexec it opens a remote cmd window on the remote pc that the end user cant see. I can still see the cmd window that I started on my laptop. the I type \\network\path\path\"myfile.bat" to run the bat file on the remote PC. When the bat file is opened I have to enter 1,2,3,4 ect. to start the bat files process. SO the whole process I do right now is type in a cmd window: psexec \\computer name -u domain\username -p password cmd. once that finishes i type \\networkpath\path\"myfile.bat". When the file is opened it needs the user to type 1,2 or 3

Comment: set /p computer-name=Enter Computer Name&wmic /node:%computer-name% /user:me /password:pass process call create "cmd \\server\share\file.bat"

Comment: This won't work \\networkpath\path\"myfile.bat".

Comment: I recently able to use vbs to push a robocopy task in hidden cmd to remote computers in background. I used WScript.Shell to exec `psexec.exe \\<COMPUTER> -accepteula -u <DOMAIN>\<USER1> -p <USER1_PWD> -e <ROBOCOPY CMD>"` and if your path/filename have spaces, `"` them! It's hard to read your post, please format the code part properly.

Comment: I have `set /p asset=Enter asset tag` then next line `psexec \\%asset% -u domain\username -p password cmd&&\\network\path\path\"myfile.cmd"` So for this will open the psexec window for the correct remote device but will not start the network path file.

Comment: Did I correctly use the && part in the code above?

Comment: No I keep telling you and showing you. \\network\path\path\"myfile.cmd" won't work. The whole path in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the solution may be implemented bypassing sending input to a cmd window, here is an example how to send the command to cmd and get back some output back:

```
Dim oShell, oExec
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = oShell.exec("%comspec%")
oExec.StdIn.Write "dir" & vbCrLf
oExec.StdIn.Write "cd c:\" & vbCrLf
oExec.StdIn.Write "dir" & vbCrLf
oExec.StdIn.Write "exit" & vbCrLf
ShowInNotepad oExec.StdOut.readall

Sub ShowInNotepad(strTest)
    Dim TempPath
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        TempPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%") & "\" & .GetTempName
        With .CreateTextFile(TempPath, True, True)
            .WriteLine(strTest)
            .Close
        End With
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe " & TempPath, 1, True
        .DeleteFile(TempPath)
    End With
End Sub
```